# Load view from Controller issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter framework and needs someone help, please.
I have an issue to redirect user back to Contact Us form after its submission.

My default controller is defined as below.

```js
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function view($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

Now my view pages are in the sub-directory called pages, for example /application/views/pages/contact-us.php. So when I access this page like http://www.example.com/contact-us then it works fine and loads the contact us form as expected.

Look at my .htaccess file that removes index.php from the URL.

```js
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And also look at my routes.php file.

```js
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['sendemail'] = 'sendemail/index';

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Now after user submits the contact us form it goes to controller called SendEmail.php and then I want user to come back to Contact Us form with message either successful or failed. I am getting an email to my gmail account but when it comes to loading VIEW it does not work.

Look at controller code of SendEmail.php

```js
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class SendEmail extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        // Check form submit or not
        //var_dump($this->input->post());

        if ($this->input->post('submit') != NULL) {

            // POST data
            $postData = $this->input->post();

            //SMTP related configuration is defined in /config/email.php
            //it loads automatically by CodIgniter
            
            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            $this->email->from($postData['email'], $postData['name']);
            $this->email->to(ADMIN_CURRENT_EMAIL);

            $this->email->subject(CONTACT_US_FORM_SUBJECT);
            $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

            $data['is_error'] = false;

            if ($this->email->send()) {
                $data['message'] = 'The email has been sent successfully.';
            } else {
                $data['is_error'] = true;
                $data['message'] = 'Sorry, the email was not sent successfully. Try again later or send a direct email to ' . ADMIN_CURRENT_EMAIL;
                //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
            
            $this->load->view('contact-us', $data);           
            
        } else {
            echo "Invalid request.";
            die();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

I am getting below error. As I said above I manage to get email to my gmail account but loading a view does not work.

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: contact-us.php

Can you please help me?

Thanks - Hitesh

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the question here and provide the link for reference. Link-only questions can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

for a redirect to the last page, you can use this code.

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```